# Requisição com Ajax e fica mostrando a mensagem Undefined após eu limpa os registros do banco de dados

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabela-html

Minha tabela mostra erro com mensagem undefined após limpa o banco de dados.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var u_descricao = $('#descricao').val();
    var u_valor = $('#valor').val();
    var u_tipo = $('#tipo').val();

            $('#form1').submit('');
            if (u_descricao == '') {
                $('#alert').html('Preencher a Descrição!.');
                $('#alert').addClass("alert-danger");
                return false;               
            }

            $('#form1').submit('');
            if (u_valor == '') {
                $('#alert').html('Preencher o Valor!.');
                $('#alert').addClass("alert-danger");
                return false;
            }

            $('#form1').submit('');
            if (u_tipo == '') {
                $('#alert').html('Preencher o Tipo!.');
                $('#alert').addClass("alert-danger");
                return false;
            }

    // console.log(u_descricao, u_valor, u_tipo);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/dispesas/modulos/cadastrar.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {descricao:u_descricao, valor:u_valor, tipo:u_tipo},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(result){
        getComments();
        $('form').trigger("reset");
                    $('#alert').html('Serviço adicionado com sucesso!');
                    $('#alert').addClass("alert-success");
                    $('#alert').fadeIn().html(result);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#alert').fadeOut('Slow');
                    },3000);
                    $('#descricao').val('');
                    $('#tipo').val('');
                    $('#valor').val('');
                    console.log(result);
    });
});


function getComments() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'config/selecionar.php',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var dados = $('.servicos');
          $('.servicos').prepend('<tr class="text-center"><td>' + result[i].descricao + '</td><td>' + result[i].tipo + '</td><td>' + result[i].valor + '</td><td>' + result[i].data + '</td></tr>');

        }
    });
}

getComments();
```

Aqui esta onde fica minha table

````
```<table class="table table-striped shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                 <thead>
                            <tr class="text-center">
                                <th> Descrição </th>
                                <th> Tipo/Serviço </th>
                                <th> Valor </th>
                                <th> Data </th>
                             </tr>
                        </thead>
                         <tbody  class="servicos">
                        </tobody> 
                    </table>  ´´´
````

[image: Erro que fica após o banco de dados esta vazio]

Answer (score -2):

Olá, se o erro está sendo apresentado após limpar os dados da tabela do banco então existe uma explicação lógica para isto, ou seja seu javascript está tentando escrever um dado que não existe, e neste caso é apresentado **undefined**.

Faça uma validação dentro da sua função de callback done, por exemplo:

```
if(typeof result[0].descricao != 'undefined') {
   /*existe dado, percorre laço e escreve na tela*/
}
```

Após isto vai parar de aparecer erros, e sua tabela html vai estar vazia.

Comment: Olá Rafael Obrigado pela resposta, o erro ainda persiste, ainda tentando resolver

Comment: Se não deu certo, tente validar de uma outra forma. Este foi apenas um exemplo de validação, portanto existe várias outras formas. Se não existe nenhum dado na sua tabela do banco de dados, então você não pode renderizar os dados tabela em sua tabela html, tens de validar antes.